# Логика работы метода push в хеш таблице

Tags: java, структуры-данных, java-hashmap

Здравствуйте, я нашел вариант реализации хэш-таблицы, но мне непонятна логика работы метода `push`:

```
public boolean push(T1 x, T2 y) {
    int h = returnHash(x); // это мы посчитали hashCode для ключа
    int i=0;
    try{
        if (table[h].isDeleted() ) { // проверили было ли там какое-то значение когда-нибудь
            table[h] = new Pair<T1, T2>(x, y);// если да то записали новое
            return true;
        }
        for (i = h + 1; i != h; i = (i + 1) % table.length) {//вот это место вообще не понятно
            if (table[i].isDeleted() || table[i].getKey() == x) {
                table[i] = new Pair<T1, T2>(x, y);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        table[h] = new Pair<T1, T2>(x, y);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Откуда взялся этот цикл? Зачем он нужен? Почему просто не проверить что ячейка `null` и записать туда, либо нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведенный Вами фрагмент реализации `HashMap` использует *метод открытой адресации* для разрешения коллизий.

В отличии от метода цепочек, где элементы с ключами, имеющими одинаковые хэш-коды, размещаются в одной корзине (в списке или дереве), в методе открытой адресации элементы с ключами, имеющими одинаковые хэш-коды, размещаются непосредственно в самом массиве (но в других корзинах).

> Откуда взялся этот цикл? Зачем он нужен?

Этот цикл используется для поиска пустой корзины для размещения в ней добавляемой пары при возникновении коллизии.

> Почему просто не проверить что ячейка `null` и записать туда, либо нет?

Если Вы внимательно посмотрите код, то здесь (в частности) это реализовано: сначала, исходя из хэш-кода ключа вычисляется номер корзины (`h`), затем происходит обращение к `table[h]`:

```
table[h].isDeleted()
```

при котором, если `table[h] == null`, то будет сгенерировано исключение `NullPointerException`, которое тут же и обрабатывается:

```
table[h] = new Pair<T1, T2>(x, y);
```

Следовательно, если в корзине с номером `h` ничего нет и не было, то пара будет размещена там, если раньше в корзине что-то было, но сейчас уже нет (случай, когда `table[h].isDeleted() == true`), то опять же пара будет размещена в этой корзине, а если корзина занята, то будет произведет поиск другой корзины, в которой и будет размещена добавляемая пара.

Хочу обратить внимание, что реализация `HashMap` из JDK использует другой метод для разрешения коллизий, а именно, *метод цепочек*.

Кстати, это какая-то весьма странная реализация добавления пары в `HashMap`:

- Если все корзины заняты, то очередная добавляемая пара **просто не будет добавлена** в `HashMap` (в данной реализации массив не расширяется и пары не перераспределяются по корзинам);
- В `HashMap` метод для вставки пары традиционно именуется как `put`, а `push` относится к стеку.

Comment: Как вот, интересно, реализован `get` в этом классе, если `push` может затолкать пару в, можно сказать, случайный индекс у `table`. Наверно, тоже циклом по всей таблице...